# Holidays planned with my new boss

Tags: new-job, vacation

I recently started a new job at a company.

During the interview process I've negotiated my vacation time with HR (3 weeks). I'm not sure if the HR representative has confirmed this with my manager. How should I approach my manager to discuss my upcoming vacation?

Comment: Have you spoken with the HR representative to see if they've confirmed this with the manager?

Comment: I haven't reached to HR after joining the company... do you think i should ask them first?

Comment: It's probably the simplest approach - I really don't see a downside to doing that.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm not too concerned about it; I simply want to know how to approach the boss in the best way possible...
I agree with EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica, I'll contact the HR and ask if they confirmed that with my boss

Comment: I don't really understand why you would feel the need to let your manager know. Unless you agree forced to take all the weeks leave at once...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't see any downside to directly talking to the H.R. rep about whether they've informed your manager or not. The standard "HR isn't your friend" line really doesn't apply here, since this is just a routine information request.

In the U.S. at least, it's completely normal and expected that you'll negotiate about stuff when you get a new job (I can't speak for other countries, though), so I don't anticipate the fact that you negotiated for more vacation would cause you any problems.

If HR already informed your manager about this, I don't think that there's anything "special" about discussing vacation schedule with your manager - you just happen to have three weeks of vacation per year. The fact that it's a new job is more relevant to how you discuss this than the fact that you negotiated for more.

Comment: I can't speak for all other countries, but in the UK your annual leave will be discussed in the interview, but it's usually not a topic for negotiation. Mainly because three weeks would be illegal here, since the statutory minimum is 5.6 weeks (or specifically 28 days).